# Javascript Associative Arrays

Tags: javascript, associative-array

It seems to me that this should work but I cant see what exactly is the problem.

The error Im receiving is "DDROA is not defined"

Could anyone help enlighten me.

```
var DDROA = {
    AllowedRoutes : {
        AR0 : {text : 'SomeText', value : 'SomeValue'},
        AR1 : {text : 'SomeText2', value : 'SomeValue2'}
    },
    RouteContext : {
        RC0 : {text : 'None', value : '0',
            AllowedRoutes : new Array(
                DDROA.AllowedRoutes.AR0  // An error occurs here
            )
        }
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

For Slack's Comment
Can you help explain why I must finish declaring the DDROA.AllowedRoutes and then make another statement to add DDROA.RouteContext in a separate stament.  Essentially you are telling me I must

```
var DDROA = {AllowedRoutes : {}};
```

then

```
DDROA.RouteContext = {};
```

Why the two separate statements.  I do things like

```
var Utilities = {
  TextBased : {
    someFunction : function(){ 
      //do stuff 
    },
    someFunction2 : function() {
      Utilities.TextBased.someFunction();
    }
  }
};
```

What is the difference? It seems to me I should get the same error?

Comment: You're misusing the `Array` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DDROA` variable is only assigned *after* the object is created.
Therefore, when the object is initialized, `DDROA` is `undefined`.

To work around it, you should set `RouteContext` separately, like this:

```
var DDROA = {
    AllowedRoutes : {
        AR0 : {text : 'SomeText', value : 'SomeValue'},
        AR1 : {text : 'SomeText2', value : 'SomeValue2'}
    }
};
DDROA.RouteContext = {
    RC0 : {text : 'None', value : '0',
        AllowedRoutes : [ DDROA.AllowedRoutes.AR0 ]  //An error does not occur here
    }        
};
```

<strike>Also, when given a single argument, the `Array` constructor takes the *length* of the array.</strike>

To make an array with a single element, use an array literal, like this  `[ DDROA.AllowedRoutes.AR0 ]`.

---

To answer your edited question, the code inside the function is only executed when the function is called, which is after the variable is assigned.

Comment: Tried this and still get the same error..same line.  Maybe some explination of why you think using a literal array definition would work instead of new Array().

Comment: The array constructor will correctly create an array with a single element if passed a single non-integer argument.  That said, probably better practice to avoid it ;o)

Comment: Mike,  I believe I have proven that the arry constructor will not create an array with a single element when passed a single non-integer argument.  Either you miss worded your comment or I am not understanding your comment.

Comment: @John: I mis-nested the braces.  It works now.  (I tried it)  Mike is correct; your `Array` constructor use is valid.

Comment: Slacks could you reveiw my edited answer I just dont understand.

Comment: @John: The array constructor will create an array with a single element when passed a non-integer argument.  Your issue was different, where the value you were attempting to assign was not yet defined.

Comment: so in this case If I trying to predefine an array I should do it outside of where I am going to use it. Im basically using these associative arrays to kinda namespace my javascript. If I predefine arrays I should probably do this in another namespace. Am I correct?  Hope that makes sence..

Comment: Another vote not to use the Array constructor. The literal is more readable and less ambiguous!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your second example works is because you're defining a function, and so the code within it isn't executed until you invoke the function, at which point your object is fully instantiated and the reference to the child object is valid. In your first example the object doesn't yet exist when you attempt to access it.